# Why does val() returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to get the value of the next hidden input field when a button is clicked but my script always returns "undefined". What am i doing wrong and why does val() returns undefined? If only try to select the element with next('input:hidden') the function returns an object.

```
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="message-ratebox">
                    <ul class="unstyled inline">
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-first" value="1">
                                Er will dich
                            </button>1
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-second" value="2">
                                Er will dich nicht
                            </button>5
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-third" value="3">
                                Es ist alles offen
                            </button>2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" name="target_message_id" value="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="message-ratebox">
                    <ul class="unstyled inline">
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-first" value="1">
                                Er will dich
                            </button>1
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-second" value="2">
                                Er will dich nicht
                            </button>5
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="rating-button" id="rating-third" value="3">
                                Es ist alles offen
                            </button>2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" name="target_message_id" value="2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.rating-button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $rating = $(this).attr('value');
        var $messageId = $(this).next('input:hidden').val();

        alert('test'+$messageId);
    });
});
```

Comment: You didn't read [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) description carefully. It gets *the immediately following **sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements.*, but your `hidden` element is not a sibling of button at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because there is no `next` element for `<button>`. You have to go up the DOM tree until `<div>` and find the hidden element:

```
var $messageId = $(this).closest(".message-ratebox").find("input:hidden").val();
```

or to go up until `<ul>` and select the `next` element:

```
var $messageId = $(this).closest("ul").next("input:hidden").val();
```

Comment: This helped me out heaps. I was using `.parent('#myDiv')` which was not having the same effect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('button.rating-button').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $rating = $(this).val();
            var $messageId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input').val();
            alert($rating + $messageId );

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse back up from the button to the input's container, which in this case is the nearest div, and then parse back down to the hidden input...

```
$('button.rating-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $rating = $(this).val();
    var $messageId = $(this).closest("div").find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    alert($rating + $messageId);
});
```